# Форма обратного заказа

Tags: php, html, javascript, форма

Ребята, подскажите, где достать форму обратного заказа. С проверкой полей на java перед отправкой данных на сервер начал делать сам, но почему-то он все равно при нажатии использует `action="имя_файла обработчика"`.

```
<form name="contact_form" method="post" action="submit.php" onsubmit="return validate_form ();">
<select id="sity" size="1" name="sity" placeholder="Выбрать город">
  <option value="Выбрать город">Выбрать город</option>
  <option value="Москва">Москва</option>
  <option value="Сочи">Сочи</option>
  <option value="Санкт-Петербург">Санкт-Петербург</option>
</select>
<select size="1" name="filials" id="filial" placeholder="Выбрать филиал">
  <option value="Выбрать филиал">Выбрать филиал</option>
  <option value="Филиал №1">Филиал №1</option>
  <option value="Филиал №2">Филиал №2</option>
  <option value="Филиал №3">Филиал №3</option>
</select>       
<input type="text" name="name_order" value="Имя" id="name" placeholder="Имя" />
<input type="text" name="phone" value="Телефон" id="tel" placeholder="Телефон" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="check" checked />
<span id="license">Я принимаю <a href="#">пользовательское соглашение</a></span>
<input id="but_call" class="red_button" name="send" type="submit" value="Купить"  />
```

Скрип обработчик:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
<!--  
function validate_form ( ){  
    valid = true;  
        if ( document.contact_form.name_order.value == "" ){  
            alert ( "Пожалуйста заполните поле 'Ваше имя'." );  
            valid = false;  
    }  
    return valid;  
}    
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Из вопроса не понятно, как именно форма должна работать?

Comment: Тут все понятно! Мне не понятно, почему он не выдает сообщение: "Пожалуйста заполните поле Ваше имя" перед отправкой формы

Comment: @ggLike, потому что name_order.value == 'Имя', а не пустой строке.
У вас же так и написано <input value="Имя" name="name_order" />

Comment: @Get т.е. к этому скрипту нужно добавить доп. условие, например: 

    else document.contact_form.name_order.value == "Имя"

Comment: Непонятно как это к java относится? Метку уберите.

Comment: такое обычно пишут в комментариях, а не в ответах

Comment: Внимательно читайте комментарии!

Comment: @ggLike, язык java и язык javascript это совершенно разные вещи, не путайте их.

Comment: Подсказка: есть высокоуровневая js библиотека jquery, для нее есть куча плагинов для валидации форм, если использовать сжатые файлы, то вес там не велик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда я писал "обработать напильником под свои нужды", я имел в виду дописать необходимые условия.

Во первых приделать форме "маркер". Условно пишу `id = 'form_zakaz'`.
Написать внутри "перехватчика", перед функцией, срабатывающей по событию click, что-нибудь вроде

```
var val_empty = $("#form_zakaz").find("#name").val();
var val_empty1 = $("#form_zakaz").find("#tel").val();
if(val_empty == "" || val_empty1 == ""){
$('form_zakaz').find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}else{
$("form_zakaz").find('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

Это для текстовых полей, если надо для других, то пишите и для других.
А уже в функции на событие click  для особо продвинутых юзеров, которые все равно будут долбить по неактивной кнопке, написать что-нибудь вроде

```
if($('form_zakaz').find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled')){
alert('Заполните обязательные поля');
}
```

Или положите сообщение в какой-нибудь div (`$('form_zakaz').find('#result(ваше место для сообщений)').innerHtml(или .text)('ваше сообщение')`), куда там вы будете выводить сообщения об ошибках, отправке и т.п. Как-то так.

P.S. Это не java, это js. Это совершенно разные вещи.

Comment: @abutan! спасибо, теперь я вас хорошо понял.

Answer (score 1):

Как точно заметил предыдущий ответчик, обработчика у вас нет. Вот рабочий пример отправки формы со скриптом для обработки ошибок и скриптом обработчикам.http://dontforget.pro/javascript/primer-ajax-otpravki-formyi-na-email-s-pomoshhyu-jquery-i-php/
Естественно, придется корректировать под свой случай, но принцип такой.

Comment: @abutan К сожалению, это не то! Мне нужно проверка формы на лету, с условием если поле не заполнено, то в input type="submit"

 action="скрипт_обработчика.php" не срабатывает.

P.S. в гугле я и сам искать умею, и в первую очередь я посмотрел этот пример и еще один похожий!

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, это не обработчик, а скрипт, который проверяет форму на стороне клиента. Тут надо поставить return false, чтобы не происходила отправка формы. Но если ошибок в форме нет, то её логичнее всего передать php (например, скрипту). Он уже занимается обработкой. Из него же можно сделать возврат на эту страничку с формой через http заголовок

```
header("Location:index.html");exit();
```

Но лучше эту форму изначально делать на ajax, чтобы не напрягать пользователя перезагрузками страницы, особенно если у вас она на каком-нибудь адаптивном лединге и ваш клиент сидит с телефона.

Answer (score 0):

Вы наверное не совсем рвзобрались с этим скриптом. Там в скрипте - "перехватчике" прописана проверка на заполненность полей, причем вы сами прописываете какие поля нужны. Эта же проверка продублирована в обработчике. Просто надо "обработать напильником" под свои нужды. Кроме того отправка формы написана на ajax и никаких перезагрузок не будет, никаких header не надо. Пример рабочий, подгонял под себя и проверял.

Comment: @abutan! Объясню по другому. Проверку я знаю как сделать! Мне нужно создать правильное условие: "если поля не заполнены то не срабатывает кнопка" т.е. method=action! Это реализуется java, как я понимаю. Я не знаю как по другому объяснить вы вопрос читали?